# Preloading videos and audio for offline use?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, offline-caching

I need to preload a web page and it's media content (video and audio) for later offline use.

The WKWebView caching works great for the web page itself, but since the audio and video were not played yet by the user, they were not stored.

Is there a way to force WKWebView to download the media content, during page load, before the user taps play?

Comment: Do you have control over the page you're loading in the webview?

Comment: @ceejayoz Technically yes.